# how to find ng-if related element in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to locate green highlighted text item. Please help

[[image: This is the real inspection1]

[image: real scenario]

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML or page url ? also tag your binding language.

Comment: Shared the code image @cruisepandey

Comment: Is it in yellow or green ?

Comment: 4 Green marked area in each row @cruisepandey

Comment: Do I have to login ?

Comment: no @cruisepandey

Comment: What is your binding language  ?

Comment: basically i need to locate the container of the text(-2.29 and all other in each row)  exist or not. @cruisepandey

Comment: i am using java @cruisepandey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236305/discussion-between-jemi-artista-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: I have given the solution below, do check it out and let me know if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xpath to locate the web elements using `findElements` :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.paysera.lt/v2/en-LT/fees/currency-conversion-calculator#/");
List<WebElement> allElements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-title='Swedbank amount']/descendant::span[contains(@data-ng-if,'getCommercialRateDifference')]"));
for(WebElement e : allElements) {
    System.out.println(e.getText());
   }
```

**Output :**

```
(-2.30)
(-426.19)
(-15.68)
(-11.05)
(-27.09)
(-2.20)
(-24.66)
(-46.94)
(-3.19)
(-1.99)
(-237.80)
(-2.81)
(-709.20)
(-15.42)
(-5.35)
(-40.92)
(-19.82)
(-18.02)
(-4.54)
(-26.13)
(-15.17)
(-87.22)
(-219.69)
(-5.00)
(-24.86)
(-173.74)
```